# Three20 TTTableViewController cell height

Tags: iphone, uitableview, three20

I'm trying to change the height of the cells in my TTTableViewController from the three20 library.
I'm using TTTableRightImageItem and I want the height to be determined by the height of the image and not the fixed height.

Do I have to subclass TableCell? Is there a property I can just set?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to subclass.

Comment: Can you give me pointers on how I do that? I assume I just create a new class myTTTableViewController which inherits from TTTableViewController and then I should override some function which tells the height of the cell? How can I find out which function is that?

Comment: You can actually keep using the controller provided by Three20 (`TTTableViewController`). What I believe you want to do is have control over the high of the cell, which is computed by each `TTTableViewItemCell`. You'll also need to choose what to use for your `TTTableViewItem` and have them mapped together in your datasource using the `-tableView:cellClassForObject:`. Unfortunately this is fairly complicated and doesn't have any good documentation yet. It's on the list of articles to write for http://new.three20.com.

Comment: Plz fix me if I'm wrong: I need to create a class which inherits from TTTabelViewController. Then, I need a custom TTTableViewItemCell, which will have the height I want (How do I create such a custom cell? subclass TTTableViewItemCell? override a height function of his? which func is that?) I saw there is "TTTableViewVarHeightDelegate" but I have no idea on how to use it. And how do I set the alignment of text inside to Right-To-Left? Hope this isn't too much to ask...

Answer (score 1):

Although probably late, but for anyone else searching set:

```
self.variableHeightRows = YES;
```

on your TTTableViewController and subclass the  TTTableRightImageItem to implement

```
+ (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*) tableView rowHeightForObject:(id)item;
```

and return the cell height in float.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `UITableViewDelegate` that you create in the `- (id<UITableViewDelegate>)createDelegate` method of `TTTableViewController` is a subclass of `TTTableViewVarHeightDelegate`.

A simple `TTTableViewDelegate` won't call the `+ (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*) tableView rowHeightForObject:(id)item;` method of your custom cell.